# Application Helper Methods Availability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4 and am trying to include the koudoku stripe gem.  Here is my routes:

```
# Added by Koudoku.
mount Koudoku::Engine, at: 'koudoku'
scope module: 'koudoku' do
    get 'pricing' => 'subscriptions#index', as: 'pricing'
end

resource :account

devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]
as :user do
    get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post '/login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end

get '/dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index'
get '/reports/generate', to: 'reports#generate'

authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'dashboard#index', :as => :authenticated_root
end

root :to => redirect('/login')
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
undefined local variable or method `root_url
```

I can access the other routes just fine, it is just trying to render the Application Helper methods (for instance, a custom app method I have defined, or routes methods) from the module routes... Does this make sense? How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you find an answer @jon

Comment: Try helper "application" or helper :all inside of the controller and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding "main_app." before your root path. For example:

```
main_app.root_path
```

Comment: This does work, but it seems kludgy that I have to add this before all my helper methods after adding this engine. Is there a way to require the helper methods in an engine?

Answer (score 0):

Conditional logic in the routing layer kind of goes against the intent of the Rails MVC architecture.  The route file should just map a web request to a controller, which then has conditional logic to determine what is displayed.

In this case it's a bit different since you want to redirect, but I personally would still put it in the controller.  In other words send the `root` to `dashboard#index`, and then at the top of that controller (or in a `before_filter`) just do

```
redirect_to login_path unless current_user_authenticated?
```

(here I'm assuming you would have a named route for login, which would be good practice, as well as a `current_user_authenticated?` method to check whatever logic you want before the redirect.  This would be a more Rails-y approach, whatever that's worth...)

Comment: I agree, however the issue is not with the protected pages... That actually works quite nice... The issue is with the "pricing" page which is given by the koudoku module.  If I access that page, it gives that error :(

Comment: Ah, got it. Have you tried using `root_path` in your controller/view?  Also, where does the stack trace say the error is happening?

Comment: Well, its weird-- cause without the module the root_path works fine.. It's in the application layout view.  But as soon as I go to a different page which is required by koudoku then it throws the error in the application view.. Almost like the application routes aren't being loaded from the inherited application controller that comes with koudoku...